# Parse Flat file every 410 characters

Tags: flat-file

I have a flat file that I need to take and insert a carriage return every 410 characters. I know this sounds weird, but for whatever reason my work was given several huge flat files from a clearinghouse, and I need to parse it out.

There is nothing that seperates what is supposed to be each new line, but it is exactly 410 characters. So I can't even search for anything specific and then do it.

There are 21 files total, each about 12-13mb.

I have asked for a CSV file, and they are unable to provide that.

I am trying to see if Notepad++ will do a Character count and then I can just hit "enter" after every 410th.

Also I am trying to see if I can do this in Java.

Any help you all can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ you can search for the regular expression `(.{410})` and replace it with `\1\r`.

It has happened to me that Notepad++ swallowed some characters when doing regex-based search and replace operations in large files, so I would try this for one file, then remove all the carriage returns again and compare the result size to the original size, just to make sure that nothing got swallowed during the replace operation.

Comment: NEvermind, just tested that, but it is actually replacing the 410 character with the return. I need to just insert it

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange: it should have replaced the 410 characters by the 410 characters (`\1`) and a carriage return (`\r`). It worked fine for me, but my test file was a lot smaller than yours. And I just noticed that you may want to have a linefeed (`\n`) instead of the carriage return - or both.

Comment: It was almost perfect, but sadly, what I was sent doesn't quite match the 410th character length that was initially told to me. Unless there is a way to strip blank space at the beginning of a line of text.

Comment: Records may be longer than 410.